# Android observer pattern and data binding, start activity when boolean property is changed

Tags: android, firebase, data-binding, firebase-authentication, reactive-programming

So I have a login activity and viewModel using firebase login and I am using data binding with it as well and I have been trying to figure out a way to get my mainActivity to run once the login method is done doing its thing, but I have yet to find some way to do it. Any help or advice is appreciated, thanks!

this is my login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer<String>{

    private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;
    private ActivityLoginBinding loginBinding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,
                R.layout.activity_login);
        loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        loginBinding.setVModel(loginViewModel);
        loginBinding.setActivity(this);

    }

    public void login(){
        String email = loginBinding.emailLginText.getText().toString();
        String password = loginBinding.pwLginTxt.getText().toString();

        loginViewModel.firebaseEmailAndPasswordAuth(email, password);

        if (loginViewModel.isAuthDone()){
            Intent sendToMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(sendToMain);
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void startSignUpActivity(){
        Intent sendToSignUp = new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(sendToSignUp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loginViewModel.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        loginViewModel.removeObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onObserve(int event, String eventMessage) {

        if (event == MyUtils.SHOW_TOAST) {
            Toast.makeText(this, eventMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (event == MyUtils.OPEN_ACTIVITY){

        }
    }
}
```

My viewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private boolean isAuthDone;
    private boolean isAuthInProgress;
    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;
    public Context mContext;


    public LoginViewModel(){
        observers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean isAuthDone(){
        return isAuthDone;
    }

    private void setAuthDone(boolean authDone){
        isAuthDone = authDone;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.authDone);
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean isAuthInProgress(){
        return isAuthInProgress;
    }

    private void setAuthInProgress(boolean authInProgress){
        isAuthInProgress = authInProgress;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.authInProgress);
    }

    public boolean isEmailAndPassValid(String email, String password){

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            return false;
        if (!MyUtils.isEmailValid(email))
            return false;
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(password);
    }

    public void firebaseEmailAndPasswordAuth(String email, String password){
        setAuthInProgress(true);

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        setAuthInProgress(false);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            setAuthDone(true);

                        } else {
                            notifyObservers(MyUtils.SHOW_TOAST, MyUtils.MESSAGE_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void addObserver(Observer client) {
        if (!observers.contains(client)) {
            observers.add(client);
        }
    }

    public void removeObserver(Observer clientToRemove) {

        observers.remove(clientToRemove);
    }

    private void notifyObservers(int eventType, String message) {
        for (int i=0; i< observers.size(); i++) {
            observers.get(i).onObserve(eventType, message);
        }
    }

}
```

and my observer interface:

```
public interface Observer<T>
{
        void onObserve(int event, T eventMessage);
}
```

Comment: Android has already prepared field like that for you : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField use the OnPropertyChangedCallback that attached to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know when the user is logged in, you should use an [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener).  In the listener callback, do whatever you need to do to continue your app.   Typically, you add one during onStart and remove it during onStop.

This is the general structure of the code.  You will want to adapt this to whatever architecture you choose:

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    public void onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseAuth auth) {
        //  Check if user is signed in and do what you want
    }
}

protected void onStart() {
    // ...
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}

protected void onStop() {
    // ...
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}
```

Comment: yeah this fixed my issue and cleaned up a ton of code